# Django MEDIA_URL, unable to source image

Tags: python, django, image

Whenever I try to run the code below I get the error:

```
the system cannot find the path specified: 'app_pickfeel/images/'
```

I'm trying to source a random image from the following directory:

```
'PickFeel/app_pickfeel/static/app_pickfeel/images'
```

Using a custom template tag (random_image.py)

**random_image.py**

```
import os
import random
from django import template
from django.conf import settings
# module-level variable
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def random_image(image_dir):
    try:
        valid_extensions = settings.RANDOM_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS
    except AttributeError:
        valid_extensions = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', ]
    if image_dir:
        rel_dir = image_dir
    else:
        rel_dir = settings.RANDOM_IMAGE_DIR
    rand_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, rel_dir)
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(rand_dir) if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in valid_extensions]
    return os.path.join(rel_dir, random.choice(files))
```

**html template:**

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{% random_image "app_pickfeel/images/" %}">
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got `/static/` in the path you're trying to reach but then you're using `MEDIA_URL` in your template and `MEDIA_ROOT` in your function. It looks to me like you need to form `rand_dir` from your static path.

Comment: `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, rel_dir)` <--> `MEDIA_ROOT = ''`